# Drupal Services AJAX to Create Node - Mobile App

Tags: cordova, drupal, service

I'm trying to create a node for forum with Drupal. I'm doing this for my mobile app so nothing lives on the server.

I've configured the whole part on the Drupal services side and was able to log in and retrieve the CSRF token but was unable to proceed with creating a node.

Particularly I'd like to create a forum node (submit new topic, create comments etc.).

Here is code, I've put comments within:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "http://example.com/rest/user/login",
      type: "POST",
      data: {"username": "admine", "password" : "pass"},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
          console.log(data.sessid) //I GET THIS 
          console.log(data.session_name) //I GET THIS

          $.ajax({
              url:"http://example.com/services/session/token",
              type:"GET",
              dataType:"text",
              crossDomain: true,
              error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  console.log(errorThrown);
              },
              success: function (token) {
                  console.log('token success: ' + token)//I GET THIS

                  $.ajaxSetup({
                      beforeSend: function (request) {
                          request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
                      }
                  });
                  var obj = {
                      "cid": 3,
                      "nid": 2,
                      "pid": 0,
                      "vid": 2,
                      "uid": 1,
                      "type": "forum",
                      "title": "win",
                      "language": "und",
                      body: {
                          "und":[
                              {
                                  "value": "win"

                          }]
                      }
                  }

                  $.ajax({
                      url: "http://example.com/rest/node",
                      type: "POST",
                      crossDomain: true,
                      setCookies: data.session_name + "=" + data.sessid,
                      //data: JSON.stringify(obj),//SHOULD I STRINGIFY IT?
                      data: obj,
                      dataType: "jsonp",
                      cache: false,
                      xhrFields: {
                          withCredentials: true
                      },

                      beforeSend: function (request) {
                          request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
                          request.setRequestHeader("Cookie", data.session_name + "=" + data.sessid);
                      },
                      success: function(data){
                          console.log(data)//HERE I GET ONLY THE NODE DATA, AS IF I'D CALL A GET METHOD ON THE URL

                      },
                      error: function(err, textStatus, errorThrown){
                          console.log(err)

                      }
                  })

              }
          });


      },
      error: function(err){
          console.log(err)
      }
  })
```

As you may see there is a bunch of stuff thrown in there with no real result. I don't get any error messages.

Does anybody have a clue how to solve this problem?

Sincerely, Jan

Answer (score 1):

Are you sending the nid? You shouldn't send nid for create.

Comment: I've tried without using the nid. Nothing changes. I still get the same response: all nodes as if I'd insert the URL into the browser.

Comment: I didn't, I did a workaround by using cURL examples. Try googling "drupal services curl example" and you'll find what you're looking for. I modified those examples with ease to work with ajax.